# Sharing internet connection from USB0 to WLAN0

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iptables

I want to create a wireless AP from my kali linux machine to share internet connection to other devices. Internet connection to linux is given by USB tethering using an android mobile phone. There is an option in linux network manager to create hotspot with 1 click and it works well, in a way that internet connection from USB0 is shared to AP created on wlan0.

This is ifconfig before turning on linux hotspot.

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:c9:c5:d8
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>             Interrupt:29

.

> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:13410 (13.0 KiB)  TX bytes:13410 (13.0 KiB)

.

> usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:24:53:78:58:7c
>             inet addr:192.168.42.106  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::bc24:53ff:fe78:587c/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:3557 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
>             TX packets:3982 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:1096856 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:719193 (702.3 KiB)

.

> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:80:93:18:2b:99
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:165261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:131910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:172078178 (164.1 MiB)  TX bytes:17919253 (17.0 MiB)

After turning on linux hotspot, it looked like this, I internet connection is shared correctly to wlan0 AP

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:90:f5:c9:c5:d8
>             UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
>             Interrupt:29

.

> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:13410 (13.0 KiB)  TX bytes:13410 (13.0 KiB)

.

> usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr be:24:53:78:58:7c
>             inet addr:192.168.42.106  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::bc24:53ff:fe78:587c/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:3634 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1
>             TX packets:4058 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:1107827 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:746531 (729.0 KiB)

.

> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:80:93:18:2b:99
>             inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::4e80:93ff:fe18:2b99/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:165261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:131960 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:172078178 (164.1 MiB)  TX bytes:17929202 (17.0 MiB)

I want to know how to do it manually with airbase-ng. I can create the AP with an interface shown as at0 in ifconfig and I can assign ip address to that, and also assign IP addresses and configure other clients using DHCP server. But I couldn't share the internet connection to that from USB0. I tried creating a network bridge but didn't work most probably because I didn't know to do that correctly.

Then I turned on hotspot with linux built in method and copied all iptables rules, created a same kind of AP with exactly similar IP addresses with airbase and restored those iptable rules, but again no luck. Same results with hostapd too.

Please tell me how to create a bridge between usb0 usb tethering network and at0(for airbase-ng) and how to set appropriate iptable rules.

Thanks.